# Group by with difference and sum

Tags: python, pandas

Here I create a dataframe for testing :

```
columns = ['A','B', 'C']
data = np.array([[1,2,2] , [1,5,4], [7,8,18]])
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
df_1
```

This renders :

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   2
1   1   5   4
2   7   8   18
```

To compute difference between 'C' and 'B' columns I use :

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_1.apply(lambda x : x['C'] - x['B'] , axis = 1))
df_2
```

This renders :

```
0   0
1   -1
2   10
```

How to group and sum the differences by column A so below dataframe is returned > :

```
1   -1
2   10
```

Here is my attempt :

```
df_1.groupby( [ "A"] ).apply(lambda x : x['C'] - x['B'] , axis = 1).sum()
```

but returns error :

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in f(g)
    705                 def f(g):
    706                     with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
--> 707                         return func(g, *args, **kwargs)
    708             else:
    709                 raise ValueError('func must be a callable if args or '

TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need subtract first and then `groupby` with `Series`:

```
df2 = (df_1['C'] - df_1['B']).groupby(df_1['A']).sum().reset_index(name='sum')
print (df2)
   A  sum
0  1   -1
1  7   10
```

Solution with `apply` - add `sum` in lambda function.
But it is slowier in larger `df`.

```
df2 = df_1.groupby("A").apply(lambda x : (x['C'] - x['B']).sum()).reset_index(name='sum')
print (df2)
   A  sum
0  1   -1
1  7   10
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(455)
columns = ['A','B', 'C']
data = np.array(np.random.randint(1000, size=(1000,3)))
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
print(df_1.head())
       A    B    C
0    789  144  421
1    392   27   95
2    960  235  750
3    300  607  422
4    363  397  252

In [154]: %timeit (df_1['C'] - df_1['B']).groupby(df_1['A']).sum().reset_index(name='sum')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.07 ms per loop

In [155]: %timeit df_1.groupby("A").apply(lambda x : (x['C'] - x['B']).sum()).reset_index(name='sum')
1 loop, best of 3: 175 ms per loop
```